# How to handle dynamic Xpath in Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I have got the Xpath of a Pay button as below

`/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[37]/td[2]/input`

However when I am sharing the script with some one else, the dynamic xpath changes to

`/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[38]/td[2]/input`

I have read few blogs to handle it dynamically using contains but I am not able to make the keyword correctly. Can anyone help me regarding this as I am new to programming?

Edit-1:

```
<tr> <td></td> 
<!--<td>
<input value="Pay in Iframe" type="submit" onclick="javascript:payInIframe();">
</td>--> 
<td>
<input value="Pay" type="submit" onclick="javascript:processTransaction();"></t‌​d> <td>
<!--<input value="CalculateChecksum" type="button" onclick="javascript:calculateCheckSum();"> 
--></td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you share the html of the element?

Comment: <input value="Pay" type="submit" onclick="javascript:processTransaction();">

Comment: Need a bit more than that to give you a proper selector :)

Comment: When I inspect element of the Pay button, this is what I get in highlighted. I am sending you the above and below lines of it as well                                                                   <tr>
     <td></td>
    <!-- <td><input value="Pay in Iframe" type="submit" onclick="javascript:payInIframe();"></td>-->
     <td><input value="Pay" type="submit" onclick="javascript:processTransaction();"></td>
     <td><!--<input value="CalculateChecksum" type="button" onclick="javascript:calculateCheckSum();"> --></td>
    </tr>

Comment: Please edit the updates into your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Always get your selector based on something meaningful and not based on the position only.

Some possible selectors in your case could be:

```
//input[@value='Pay'][contains(@onclick, 'processTransaction')]
//input[contains(@onclick, 'processTransaction')]
//table//tbody//input[contains(@onclick, 'processTransaction')]
```